# How to add dependency independent of another bundle in AEM

Tags: java, maven, aem, dependency-management, bnd

I want to add a dependency specifically [webp-imageio-sejda](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sejda.webp-imageio/webp-imageio-sejda) in my current project (project A), for this jar to be available to my bundle I have to embed it. In my AEM instance there already exist a bundle (project B) which  already contains the same dependency and it is also embedded into that bundle.

Project A pom.xml :

```
   ......
    <Embed-dependency> webp-iamgeio </Embed-dependency>
   ......

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sejda.imageio/webp-imageio -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sejda.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>webp-imageio</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.6</version>
        <scope> provided </scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Project B POM.xml

```
.....
    <Embed-dependency> webp-iamgeio </Embed-dependency>
......

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sejda.imageio/webp-imageio -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sejda.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>webp-imageio</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.6</version>
        <scope> provided </scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The problem is when I deploy my bundle (Project A) and run any service which is using a class (WebPWriteParam) from  webp-imageio-sejda I am facing an error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebPWriteParam cannot be cast to class com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebPWriteParam

This is because I have same JAR embedded in two different bundles. (Project A and Project B). I cannot Edit the POM of Project B.

Any idea How can I resolve this issue.

One solution I found that I can upload jar as an bundle and use that in both the bundles without embedding but I cannot edit the POM in the second bundle to remove embedding.

Thanks

AEM Community Post : https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/how-to-add-dependency-independent-of-another-bundle/td-p/548894

Comment: Is this an OSGi project?

Comment: Yes @khmarbaise

Comment: It is an AEM Project which uses felix maven-bundle-plugin for building. Thanks

Comment: is that `webp-imageio-sedja` an osgi bundle? if not, you should make an osgi wrapper for it. register it as service, then use it as a service as god (at least people who wrote osgi) intended. sorry i can't guide you on how to exactly do that, i don't have aem (or any osgi container) at hand to play with.

Comment: Thanks @BagusTesa but actually I cannot remove dependency from the Project B. If I deploy the `webp-imageio-sedja` as a wrapper then It will create same problem in the project B.

Comment: @VishnuJangid if you are confident that the library in project B will work as you expected (same version, and always available), you can change the dependency scope to `provided` and dont ember it. else, just take the source for that `webp-imageio-sedja` and put it in your source with different namespace. you can only do the latter if that library license allows it, consult a lawyer. i wont write this as an answer, the last guy accepted answer that changed his question even though hes adamant "it cant be changed."

Comment: Thanks @BagusTesa but the library is not exported by project B so I cannot use it. also cannot edit anything in project B.